# What causes mdx Script errors in Excel Power Pivot?

Tags: excel, dax, powerquery, powerpivot

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoNJw.png)

Details:

- data source: excel workbooks available through remote desktop.
- loaded into the data model with power query
  -The measure:
  SUMX(
  'FACT TABLE';
  'FACT TABLE'[Amount] * RELATED('DIM TABLE'[Positive])
  )

I'm able to load all tables, no errors in the measure. I'm able to add my measure to the pivot table, however I receive this error message when attempting to edit, rename or delete it.

What could cause this error and how to solve it?

Please let me know if additional information is needed.

I've tried renaming the tables, rebuilding the data model, and recreating the measure, nothing worked unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a potential modification to your DAX measure:

```
SUMX(
    VALUES('FACT TABLE'[YourUniqueColumn]),
    RELATED('DIM TABLE'[Positive]) * CALCULATE(SUM('FACT TABLE'[Amount]))
)
```

Replace `YourUniqueColumn` with the unique column from 'FACT TABLE' that can be used as a filter context.

If there are unused or unnecessary relationships in your data model, consider clearing them and If your DAX measure involves large datasets, consider optimizing it for performance. This may involve using more efficient DAX functions or breaking down the measure into smaller parts.